# SC 8 Experience Editor RTE breaks when it has a list in it

Tags: experience-editor, richtext-editor

Has anybody seen this behaviour before... I add a RTE (via a rendering with a local datasource) to a page via Experience Editor...  edit the text, add some text and styling etc.  Save... all ok

Add a list (ordered list for example), then save... saves fine but I now can't access the field via the EE... clicking on it selects only the container, not the actual field.

Any ideas?  Smells like a bug to me...

SC 8.1.151003

Comment: Do you see any JS errors after editing the RT?

Comment: Did you see any browser console error when you save the content ?
we have noticed similar behavior with RTE while inserting '%' special character & an error log in browser console. After some analysis we came to know its an RTE issue. Sitecore provided a fix through support ticket.
we are using Sitecore 8.1 Update 1 (151207) If it is possible please share your content to replicate the issue from my end.
i.e. in html formate

Comment: @BalajiKuppuswamy What do you mean "in html formate"?

There's no (relevant) console errors... it appears if i add a list to a block, then go to another block and come back to that one, i can edit it... but once i've saved the page, hovering over that block shows the hand instead of the caret (so i can only select the rendering, not the content of the rendering).  It works fine after multiple saves without a list in the field.

Definitely looks like a bug.. i'll log it with sitecore

Comment: @Jeeby take a look at the html source tab and see if there is a nested <p> tag or something around the list as I've seen that break experience editor before when there is invalid html being rendered.

Comment: I'll check that on MOnday @aseabridge, however I don't think that's the case as i can add and edit renderings with ricth text editor data sources without issue, until i add one with a list (i think that's the breaking factor) which then causes any renderings added after that point to not be editable.

I haven't investigated this enough to understand exactly what the behaviour is - I'll come back to after this sprint when things have calmed down a bit and I have some spare time.